# Installing VTK 5 for mayavi with Homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew, vtk, mayavi

I am trying to install Mayavi fro Python on Mac OS X Mavericks using Homebrew and pip. I am stuck because of an unclear error related to VTK: I have installed VTK 5 with Homebrew using

```
brew reinstall --python --qt vtk5
```

and tried to install Mayavi with

```
pip install mayavi
```

but I just  get en error output which ends with

```
ImportError: No module named vtkCommonCorePython
```

I thought about an issue with my PYTHONPATH variable, but I cannot find where vtkCommonCorePython is located. My PYTHONPATH is

```
/Users/ft14968/Scripts:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:usr/local/opt/vtk5/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Is there a way to circumvent this issue, or to install a working python VTK binding with Homebrew?

Comment: FWIW: An alternative if you were not committed to Homebrew, would be to use Canopy's free install, from which which you can click-install VTK 5.10 and Mayavi 4.4, pre-built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `brew reinstall --python --qt vtk5`

Check `brew info` for exactly what formula options are available. For vtk5, the options you're looking for are `--with-python --with-qt`. Anything unrecognized is ignored.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I got confused by tutorials like this http://davematthew.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/installing-matplotlib-and-mayavi-on-mac.html

Comment: There's a method to point old options to new ones so I've added that for --qt and --python, thanks for the link.

Comment: It may be necessary to run `brew tap homebrew/science` before `vtk5` will be available.

Comment: Isn't the `--qt` switch optional?

Comment: FYI, the most current version does python bindings by default (meaning you don't have to set any flags). You may have to update your `PYTHONPATH` after installation. Brew will tell you what to do. If you **don't** want python bindings, you do `--without-python`.